# UK transit VISA for Indian Citizens

Tags: british-airways

Am an Indian Citizen travelling to Ireland with an Irish visa via LHR so would I need a transit visa at London Heathrow airport?

Comment: Will you stay airside or will you go through passport control at Heathrow for the transit?

Comment: i would be stayin airside as i would have to board the next flight in an hour.

Comment: @EMotion Absolutely irrelevant. Even if he did Need to clear immigration he could on the basis of a biometric Irish visa

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Irish visa.

According to [this](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) GOV.UK document, as an Indian national, you need a Direct Airside Transit Visa *unless* you have an Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section).

Comment: that sounds helpful I shall do some research on this as well